# Reading foreign key ref in save() override raises RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I suppose this is by design, but here's my scenario: if saving a Child without a Parent, I want to create a new Parent.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    pass

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='children')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.parent is None: # error happens here
            self.parent = Parent.objects.create()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

c = Child()
c.save()
# django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Child has no parent.
```

I get the above RelatedObjectDoesNotExist when executing `if self.parent is None`. I've tried `if not self.parent` as well, same error on the same line. I don't really want to make the parent field nullable. Just the act of reading self.parent, even to check if it's None, is enough to trigger the error.

This is in Django 1.11, here's where the error is raised: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2b882a4bd954c8a6b1447f8fc0841a3352514c26/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L193, so if I'm reading this right, just by reading self.parent, I'm ending up in that `__get__`.

How can I "give it a value if it's None", if I can't check that it's None?

Comment: Well the problem is that you do not specify that the `parent` can be `NULL`, hence Django will query and assume that it contains a parent.

Comment: Right. Is there any way, in the Child's save() override, to accomplish "if saving a Child without a Parent, create and reference a new Parent"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that accessing the FK itself causes a database lookup, which is failing. To avoid that, access the underlying ID field:

```
if self.parent_id is None:
```

Comment: Oops, of course, thanks Daniel. I sometimes forget about those auto-generated fields.